# No converter found capable of converting from type org.bson.types.ObjectId to type int (help)

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring data and mongodb to get all test data using this function:

when I run this

```
        List<Test> tests = mongoOps.findAll(Test.class);
    for(Test test : tests){
        log.info(test.toString());
    }
```

**my document:**

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56a09fd614923217ac1c545f"), 
"id" : 1.0, 
"address" : [
    1.0, 
    2.0, 
    3.0
]
```

}

my Test class

```
@Document(collection = Test.COLLECTION_NAME)
```

public class Test {

```
public static final String COLLECTION_NAME = "test";

@Id
private int id;
private List<Double> address;

public Test(int id, List<Double> address) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.address = address;
}
```

}

Error:

```
No converter found capable of converting from type org.bson.types.ObjectId to type int
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `id` property is not the identifier of the document in the database. `_id` is. You should be able to read this by tweaking your domain class to:

```
 class Test {

   @Id ObjectId databaseId;
   int id;
   …
 }
```

`@Id` references the document identifier, which in your case is an `ObjectId`. Read more on that in the [Spring Data MongoDB reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.conventions.id-field)